# Zookeeper cannot be launched remotely via ssh

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

Strange issue:
The zookeeper works normally on my cluster if I start it using `./zkServer.sh` on each machine, respectively.

However, when I try to start it remotely from the master node:

```
ssh 192.168.xxx.xxx "/opt/apache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh start"
```

it looks fine:

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/apache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

But actually, zookeeper is **not** running on that machine, which can be confirmed by `jps`.

The **most strange** thing is:
If I directly start zookeeper on that node using `./zkServer.sh start` then I **can** successfully stop it remotely from the master node using

```
ssh 192.168.xxx.xxx "/opt/apache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh stop"
```

Why could this happen? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `ssh $host "nohup $command"` ?

Comment: ssh 192.168.xxx.xxx "nohup  /opt/apache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh start"      this does not work either....  @CostiCiudatu

Comment: Have you tried if the full path version of the command works locally? Basically, instead of `./zkServer.sh start`, cd into somewhere else and try `/opt/apache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh start`. Not sure if this makes sense, but I remember that at some point the startup script had some issues with different working dirs.

Answer (score 0):

Though after a lot of search I was able to get it, below is the command that successfully starts it.

```
ssh -i "somekey.pem" username@hostname 'bash -i -c "~/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start"'
```